# MXE compile on linux for linux

Tags: mxe

So I saw this project http://mxe.cc/ and tried it, it seems like it is very easy to compile stuff for windows with this. I tried to hack it a little bit to compile binaries for linux instead, because, if it compiles for other system so easily how can it be hard to compile for host? 90% of the stuff seems to just build out of the box, but there are some errors and therefore I cannot build. I want to ask, how correctly should I configure mxe to build for the linux host? I know this is not supported but I don't think it should be that hard because we build from source anyway. And there are next to no modifications for downloaded sources too (in a windows build that is).

For people who might ask why I don't want to use shared stuff, I want to basically have two options:

1. dpkg package for user with dependencies specified (the linux way)
2. single standalone static executable

Any suggestions? Or maybe there's whole another guide on linux on how to build things from scratch (without a lot of manual work like mxe does)?